# android : Error loading Realm db file from assets

Tags: android, realm

I got a realm db file from our iOS app and want to ship it as part of our app in android. This is the first time we are shipping this, so there are no migration problems. So, I clean installed the app and try to run it in an activity using the below code:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new     RealmConfiguration.Builder(TestActivity.this)
                    .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                    .assetFile(TestActivity.this, MY_DB_FILE_NAME)
                    .build();


            Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
            Log.d(TAG,"Config schema version"+config.getSchemaVersion());
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            if (realm.isEmpty()) {
                subscriber.onError(new Exception("Realm db is empty"));
            } else {
                realm.close();
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
```

I am using realm 1.0.0

from my gradle :

```
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
```

Problem : I see below exception.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Realm on disc is newer than the one specified: v1 vs. v0

This is the first time I am loading, no migration. Why do I get this error ?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: yes I'm getting same issue, hope something comes to help

Answer (score 0):

if you don't specify the schema version, Realm assumes it to be 0 whileas that of your asset is 1. This becomes noticed later when Realm gets evaluated internally. You can solve this by providing a version.

```
RealmConfiguration config = new       RealmConfiguration.Builder(TestActivity.this)
                .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                .assetFile(TestActivity.this, MY_DB_FILE_NAME)
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .build();
```

Comment: didnt work.   W/System.err: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: RealmMigration must be provided
W/System.err:     at io.realm.BaseRealm.migrateRealm(BaseRealm.java:680)
W/System.err:     at io.realm.Realm.migrateRealm(Realm.java:1221)
W/System.err:     at io.realm.Realm.migrateRealm(Realm.java:1208)
W/System.err:     at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:235)
W/System.err:     at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:126)
W/System.err:     at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:192)

Comment: RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(ctx)
                        .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                        .assetFile(TestActivity.this, MY_DB_FILE_NAME)
                        .schemaVersion(1)
                        .build();

                Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
                Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
                if (realm.isEmpty()) {
                    subscriber.onError(new Exception("Realm is empty"));
                } else {
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }

Comment: What version of realm are you running on iOS, 1.0.0?